# Unhandled exception event handler not called when exception is thrown from Express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, exception

I wrote a simple Express route to test my event handler for uncaught exceptions, but for some reason when throwing from the route code, the event handler is not being called:

```
app.js:

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.log('Handling exception');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Serving request');
    throw(new Error('Some error'));
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8888; 
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

When send a GET request, I see the following output on the screen (call stack abbreviated for better readability):

```
Listening on port 8888...
Serving request
Error: error
    at app.get (/Users/omerah/Documents/playground/node/hello-server/app.js:48:11)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/omerah/Documents/playground/node/hello-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/omerah/Documents/playground/node/hello-(/Users/omerah/Documents/playground/node/hello-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/omerah/Documents/playground/node/hello-
...
```

Following is the structure of my code (a simplified version). The exceptions are thrown from code under the 'routes' folder and should be catch be the event handler that is defined in app.js:

```
├── [-rw-r--r--]  app.js
├── [-rw-r--r--]  authenticate.js
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  routes
|   ├── [-rw-r--r--]  login.js
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  modles
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  utils
```

Why isn't the event handler being called?

Comment: Where your process.on code is located? Give file's structure please. And anyway there is another pattern of errors handlers in express, see this https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2854ef613751563a3b506fabce4501fd

Comment: I', aware of the fact that this is not the proper way of handling exceptions, however I'd like to log all uncaught exceptions in a file so I can later on add the missing try/catch blocks. I'm using winston to log all uncaught exceptions, but since express catches these exceptions, they are not being logged. I added the file structure to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `process.on('uncaughtException', () => {})` to catch errors in express. You can create a custom event handler middleware through something like:

```
function myCustomErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  if (<check on error>) {
    console.log('Handling exception');
    // TODO: Optionally, return a response back here using "res"
  }

  next(error);
}
```

You can use this custom handler

```
app.use(myCustomErrorHandler);
```